# Convert an array of file path to array of files and calculate the size of each

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield, filesize

I have a `JTextField` in which the user has to enter file path separated by comma

I take the text field value into an array:

```
String[] filename = filename.split(","); // where filename is the jtextfield value
```

I need to check the size of each file in the array.

If the file size is more than 10 MB, I need to inform the user.

How to convert an array of file path to array of files and calculate the file size of each file in Java?

I tried using :

```
File[] files = new File[filename.length];    

for(int i=0;i < filename.length;i++){    
    long filesizeinbytes=files[i].length;    
    long filesizeinkb= filesizeinbytes/1024;    
    long filesizeinmb=filesizeinkb/1024;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `initialize` each element in the `files` array. It would throw a `NPE`.

```
long totalFileSizeOfAllFiles = 0;
for(int i=0;i < filename.length;i++){    
    files[i] = new File(filename[i]); // This is required.
    long filesizeinbytes=files[i].length(); // Also length is a method.
    totalFileSizeOfAllFiles+=filesizeinbytes; // To get the total size of all the files present.
```

**P.S:-** The assumption here is that each entry in the `filename[]` array is a proper **absolute/relative path** to each file under consideration!

Comment: Then this should work. Do note that I've not provided the `if` condition to check for the `size > 10 MB` scenario. Do add that and check if it works or not!

Comment: no. when i print the filesizeinmb, it says 0 MB. I have around 5 excel files. each around 55 kb in size

Comment: need to check the total file size of the files in the array

Comment: no matter what i change in teh code, the filesizeinmb shows o MB only

Comment: filesizeinbytes and filesizeinkb displays correctly. but filesizeinmb shows 0 MB.

Comment: i took filesizeinmb as double. i get the size now. but how do i total the file size? (sum of all file sizes in the array)

Comment: Check my update! I've added a new variable(`totalFileSizeOfAllFiles`) for that purpose. Do change the name of the var as per your needs!

Answer (score 0):

seems there is something missing here
where do you create the File object inside the array

```
File[] files = new File[filename.length];    
for(int i=0;i < filename.length;i++){    
    File f = new File(filename[i]);
    long filesizeinbytes=f.length();    
    long filesizeinkb= filesizeinbytes/1024;    
    long filesizeinmb=filesizeinkb/1024;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String path:fileName){
File file=new File(path);

long fileSizeInBytes = file.length();
long fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
long fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;

if (fileSizeInMB > 10) {
 // code to iform user
}
}
```

Comment: sorry, i thought that i had written that, but missed that part. but, the size always says, 0MB only.............